# php mysql with regex capablity

Tags: php, mysql

I have this script and working just fine with basic search and I am thinking add regex capability user can search like (a*) and display all results start with A so on. is that possible to modify this scrip or I need totally new script. this is not for public interface web site.

```
<?php
$query = $_GET['query']; 
if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ // if query length is more or equal minimum length  then
     $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
  $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles
        WHERE (`ProductName` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`PrductMF` LIKE '%".$query."%')") or die(mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do following
          while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){
                    echo "<p><h3>".$results['ProductName']."   </h3>".$results['PoductMF']."</p>";
             }
          }
    else{ 
        echo "No results";
    }
     }
   ?>
```

Comment: **Careful!** The `mysql_*` functions are [old and should not be used anymore](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). Please have a look at [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli), which are better [MySQL API choices](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Comment: thanks I will consider PDO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can probably try RLIKE

```
<?php
$query = $_GET['query']; 
if(strlen($query) >= $min_length){ // if query length is more or equal minimum length  then
     $query = mysql_real_escape_string($query);
  $raw_results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles
        WHERE (`ProductName` RLIKE '".$query."') OR (`PrductMF` RLIKE '".$query."')") or die(mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($raw_results) > 0){ // if one or more rows are returned do following
          while($results = mysql_fetch_array($raw_results)){
                    echo "<p><h3>".$results['ProductName']."   </h3>".$results['PoductMF']."</p>";
             }
          }
    else{ 
        echo "No results";
    }
     }
   ?>
```

important: \w \s \d doesn't work on mysql, you should use something like [[:alnum:]] ([a-zA-Z0-9]) [[:space:]] (not exactly like \s) [[:digit:]] and so on,

you can more at:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html